# Different behaviour of listdir in python installed on ubuntu and windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I creat A folder and inside that folder i create 4 more folders name 1, 2, 3, 4 (just empty). And use them i am us

```
import os
data_path='/home/nd/Desktop/directory1'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)
```

The above code show different behaviour on spyder installed on ubuntu and windows. (Python 3.6, ubuntu 16.04 , windows 10). For ubuntu `data_dir_list='1', '2', '4', '3'` and for windows it is '1', '2', '3', '4'.
[image] [image]

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir): *"The list is in arbitrary order"*.

Comment: But listdir doesnot show arbitrary order on spyder installed on windows. I tried with more folders.

Comment: I don't think you know what the word "arbitrary" means.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, on large data it is showing arbitrary behavior on both os.

Comment: "arbitrary" doesn't mean "unsorted". Do yourself a favor and look it up.

Comment: yup you are correct. my mistake